# IdP initiated SSO using custom library

Tags: saml-2.0

I have a custom MVC solution based on user login through database based user validation. Now I want to send a SAML token by doing a IDP initiated SSO which will send my user data to service provider using X.509 based encryption.

I don't want to use any external Identity Provider for that. Is there any open source Java library through which I can generate a SAML token from my custom JEE application?

Answer (score -1):

There are a number detailed here: [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](https://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).

Comment: Why the downvote? You can do this e,g, with OpenSAML which is in that list.